fl_chart spots generation completion
I am using fl_chart to create a graph. I am using a function to create spots dynamically. There is a delay sfter the spots are created for the graph to display. Is there a way to know when fl_chart has finished creting the graph fully. I can then display a spinner to show graph is being built.
Tried setting flags when my function has finished creating spots but not sure to find when the graph has finished plotting these spots
var newSpots = updatedDailyTotals.asMap().entries.map((e) {
      final dailyTransaction = e.value; // Get the TransactionAmount object
      return FlSpot(e.key.toDouble(),
          dailyTransaction.totalAmount); // Create FlSpot with index and amount
    }).toList();

minX: 0,
      maxX: xAxisCount,
      minY: 0,
      maxY: yAxisCount,
      lineBarsData: [
        LineChartBarData(
          preventCurveOverShooting: true,
          spots: graphSpots,
          isCurved: true,
          gradient: LinearGradient(
            colors: gradientColors,
          ),
          barWidth: 5,
          isStrokeCapRound: true,
          dotData: const FlDotData(
            show: false,
          ),
          belowBarData: BarAreaData(
            show: true,
            gradient: LinearGradient(
              colors: gradientColors
                  .map((color) => color.withOpacity(0.3))
                  .toList(),
            ),

